# How make a projection according to a conditional without subquery using nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, if-statement, subquery, queryover

In my query a person can have several positions.

Person -> Job [IdJob]

Need to make a projection for the manager position for a field and another projection for the position of manager for other field

without using subquery. Can it be done?

Exemple:

> .SelectList (Sl => sl 
>         .SelectGroup (S => s. Name) .WithAlias ​​(() => rel. Individual) 
>         Where (() => Person.idJob = 1)
>
> / * Funcionaraia as if, in here I could design a board member to the Administrator class field projected * /
>
> .SelectGroup (S => s. Name) .WithAlias ​​(() => rel. Administrator)
>
> Where (() => Person.idJob = 2)
>
> / * Manager for the same * /
>
> .SelectGroup (S => s. Name) .WithAlias ​​(() => rel. Managers)

Answer (score 0):

```
var personName = Projections.Property<Person>(p => p.Name);
var none = Projections.Constant(null);
session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Select(
        Projections.Conditional(Expression.Where<Person>(p => p.Job == Job.Manager), personName, none).WithAlias(() => rel.Manager),
        Projections.Conditional(Expression.Where<Person>(p => p.Job == Job.Administrator), personName, none).WithAlias(() => rel.Administrator),
        Projections.Conditional(Expression.Where<Person>(p => p.Job == Job.Employee), personName, none).WithAlias(() => rel.Individual)
        );
```

Comment: Thanks Firo! Have an error in attribute "none" -> The name "none" does not exists in the context. Dont context But anyway, i need of two conditionals for verify the person has active job for example. This case require the subquery, right ?

Comment: none is a local variable defined just above the query. How can it be unknown? If your Job is an entity and you need restrictions on that you need a subquery which is accessible through `Subqueries` class